# Accessing javascript instance member when passing the method

Tags: javascript, scope

I wrote some code like this

```
function Flasher() {
    this.cards = []
    this.map = {
        14: this.flip
    }
}
Flasher.prototype.flip = function() {
    alert(this.cards.length)
}
flasher = new Flasher()
flasher.map[14]()
```

Unfortunatley, the `this` object becomes the map object within the `flip` method and an error occurs (because `cards` is undefined).

How can I get this to function as intended? Calling `flip` indirectly via `map` is necessary, but I would like access to the original object within `flip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Flasher() {
    var self = this;

    this.cards = [];
    this.map = {
        14: function() { self.flip(); }
    };
}
```

Comment: To the OP: A prototype function needs to always be tied to a context, you should never assign a function to something else (if it needs `this`), because it probably won't be called with the correct context; John's answer forces `flip` to be called with the correct context;

Answer (score 1):

Ah the hassles of the protoype pattern

I would rewrite it as a module like so:

```
function flasher() {
  var cards = [],
  flip = function (){
    alert(cards.length)
  },
  map = {
    14: flip
  };

  return {
    cards: cards,
    map: map,
    flip: flip
  };
}
```

Then the closure captures your scope and you never need to worry about **this**. You lose a bit of memory though as your flip function is replicated for each object. But I think the code is a lot cleaner and it allows for private variables.

Comment: You lose a lot of memory if you reuse the object a lot

Comment: @JuanMendes these days we have a lot of memory. If there was only going to be 10 of them...well it doesn't matter. If there was going to be 10,000 of them I'd use the prototype. But the module pattern is clearer and avoids a lot of other issues so it ends up being easier for the developer. (which matters more most of the time)

Comment: @aranmulholland1 That's the million dollar question.  I don't have problems with the this keyword, so I think avoiding the prototype for that reason is throwing the baby out with the bath water, it's usually the same people that don't like using new